# Unable to a print in Windows 10 when Delphi / QuickReport is within a DLL

Tags: delphi, quickreports

Delphi 7 / QuickReport 5.02.2

We've used similar code for several years but have run into an issue recently now that we're migrating workstations to Windows 10. Previously, we were using Windows 7 and all was fine. Maybe there's something I'm missing or doing wrong?

Here's a simple test project I put together to test this. When the report is within a DLL every call to `Printer.GetPrinter` fails in Windows 10. Though, if the report is on a form within the main application it works fine.

Below is the code, and a zipped up folder for anyone that's interested. There is the dependency on QuickReport though, which can't be helped.  Thanks for looking.

https://1drv.ms/u/s!AsbtokV75aocsXM6MQZcrvwpHKcg

DLL Project.

```
library test_dll;

uses
  SysUtils,
  Classes,
  Forms,
  report in 'report.pas' {report_test};

{$R *.res}

function Report_Print(PrinterName: Widestring): Integer; export;
var
  Receipt: Treport_test;
begin
  try
    Receipt := Treport_test.Create(nil);
    try
      Receipt.Print(PrinterName);
      Receipt.Close;
    finally
      Receipt.Free;
    end;
  except
    Application.HandleException(Application.Mainform);
  end;
  Result := 1;
end;

exports
  Report_Print;
begin

end.
```

Report Unit

```
unit report;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, QRCtrls, QuickRpt, ExtCtrls, Printers, QRpCtrls, QRPrntr;

type
  Treport_test = class(TForm)
    QuickRep1: TQuickRep;
    DetailBand1: TQRBand;
    TitleBand1: TQRBand;
    QRLabel1: TQRLabel;
    SummaryBand1: TQRBand;
    QRLabel2: TQRLabel;
    QRLabel3: TQRLabel;
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  procedure Print(const PrinterName: string);
  end;

var
  report_test: Treport_test;

procedure SetupPrinter(QuickRep: TQuickRep; const PrinterName: string);
function SelectPrinter(QuickRep: TQuickRep; const PrinterName: string): boolean;

implementation

var
  DLL_QRPrinter: TQRPrinter;

{$R *.dfm}

function SelectPrinter(QuickRep: TQuickRep; const PrinterName: string): boolean;
var
  i: integer;
  compareLength: integer;
  windowsPrinterName: string;
  selectedPrinter: Integer;
  defaultPrinterAvailable: Boolean;
begin
  defaultPrinterAvailable := True;
  try // an exception will occur if there is no default printer
    i := Printer.printerIndex;
    if i > 0 then ; // this line is here so Delphi does not generate a hint
  except
    defaultPrinterAvailable := False;
  end;

  compareLength := Length(PrinterName);
  if (not Assigned(QuickRep.QRPrinter)) then
  begin
    QuickRep.QRPrinter := DLL_QRPrinter;
  end;
  // Look for the printer.
  selectedPrinter := -1;

  // Attempt #1: first try to find an exact match
  for i := 0 to QuickRep.QRPrinter.Printers.Count - 1 do
  begin
    windowsPrinterName := Copy(QuickRep.QRPrinter.Printers.Strings[i], 1, compareLength);
    if (UpperCase(windowsPrinterName) = UpperCase(PrinterName)) then
    begin
      selectedPrinter := i;
      Break;
    end;
  end;

  // Attempt #2: if no exact matches, look for the closest
  if (selectedPrinter < 0) then
    for i := 0 to QuickRep.QRPrinter.Printers.Count - 1 do
    begin
      windowsPrinterName := Copy(QuickRep.QRPrinter.Printers.Strings[i], 1, compareLength);
      if (Pos(UpperCase(PrinterName), UpperCase(QuickRep.QRPrinter.Printers.Strings[i])) > 0) then
      begin
        selectedPrinter := i;
        Break;
      end;
    end;

  // Attempt #3: if no exact matches, and nothing close, use default printer
  if (selectedPrinter < 0) and (defaultPrinterAvailable) then
    selectedPrinter := QuickRep.Printer.printerIndex;

  Result := False;
  if (selectedPrinter > -1) then
  begin
    QuickRep.PrinterSettings.PrinterIndex := selectedPrinter;
    Result := True;
  end;
end;

procedure SetupPrinter(QuickRep: TQuickRep; const PrinterName: string);
begin
  //check if we have the default printer instead of the selected printer
  SelectPrinter(QuickRep, PrinterName);

  QuickRep.Page.Units := Inches;
  QuickRep.Page.Length := 11;
end;

procedure Treport_test.Print(const PrinterName: string);
begin
  SetupPrinter(QuickRep1, PrinterName);
  QuickRep1.Print;
end;

initialization
  DLL_QRPrinter := TQRPrinter.Create(nil);

finalization
  DLL_QRPrinter.Free;
  DLL_QRPrinter := nil;
end.
```

Test Application

```
program Project1;

uses
  Forms,
  Unit1 in 'Unit1.pas' {Form1};

{$R *.res}

begin
  Application.Initialize;
  Application.CreateForm(TForm1, Form1);
  Application.Run;
end.
```

Main Form

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms, QRPrntr,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls, QuickRpt, QRCtrls, ExtCtrls, Printers, QRPCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;

    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

type
  TPrintReport = function(PrinterName: Widestring): Integer;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

procedure PrintReport(const PrinterName: string);

implementation

var
  DLLHandle: THandle = 0;
    POS: TPrintReport = nil;

{$R *.dfm}

procedure PrintReport(const PrinterName: string);
begin
  try
    POS(PrinterName);
  except on e: Exception do
    ShowMessage(e.Message);
  end;
end;

procedure LoadDLL;
var
  DLLName: string;
  DLLRoutine: PChar;
begin
  DLLName := 'test_dll.dll';
  DLLRoutine := 'Report_Print';
  if not (FileExists(DLLName)) then
    raise Exception.CreateFmt('The DLL "%s" is missing. Build the DLL project and try again.', [DLLName]);

  Application.ProcessMessages;
  DLLHandle := LoadLibrary(PChar(DLLName));
  Application.ProcessMessages;

  if (DLLHandle = 0) then
    raise Exception.CreateFmt('Error: %s, while attempting to load DLL %s.', [IntToStr(GetLastError), DLLName]);

  POS := GetProcAddress(DLLHandle, DLLRoutine);
  if (@POS = nil) then
    raise Exception.CreateFmt('Error: %s, while attempting get address to %s in DLL %s.', [IntToStr(GetLastError), DLLRoutine, DLLName]);
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  LoadDLL;
  ShowMessage('dll loaded');
  PrintReport('MyPrinter');
  FreeLibrary(DLLHandle);
end;

end.
```

Snippet from QuickReport

```
procedure TPrinterSettings.ApplySettings;
var
  Cancel : boolean;
begin
  FPrinter.GetPrinter(FDevice, FDriver, FPort, DeviceMode);
  DevMode := GlobalLock(DeviceMode);
  begin
    SetField(dm_paperlength); 
...
```

DeviceMode is 0, so SetField throws an access violation. See below.

Access violation at address 036BFBA7 in module 'test_dll.dll'. Write of address 00000028.

Comment: You say the call to GetPrinter fails, but what is the exact error?

Comment: Yes, sorry I didn't cover that. There's an access violation.  I added a snippet of the QuickReport code to my original question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try comment out those 2 lines for GetPrinter and for DevMode

```
procedure TPrinterSettings.ApplySettings;
var
  Cancel : boolean;
begin
  // FPrinter.GetPrinter(FDevice, FDriver, FPort, DeviceMode);
  // DevMode := GlobalLock(DeviceMode);
  begin
    SetField(dm_paperlength); 
   ...
end
```

Comment: I'm not sure if that worked for you, or if you're just suggesting it. But when I commented out those two lines, it causes an AV in the constructor.

Comment: @fourwhey we are using 5.06 quickreport and I checked the source code those 2 lines have been commented out. that's why I suggested it. but apparently there are some other changes I didn't know as well.

Comment: I see. I guess other things have changed between versions. If you have Windows 10, can you try building and running my example project? I'm curious if the problem exists in later builds. I've contacted the QuickReport developer about what I'm experiencing, but I don't have high hopes since they gave me a non-committal response about looking into it. Thanks!

Comment: tried your code, build dll is ok, but test project won't start

Comment: Is it crashing with AV or something else? If you look in the DLL folder, you can debug the DLL code and step into the printing route if point Run Parameters/Host Application to the exe in the main folder.

Comment: I downloaded the source for 5.06 and backed all of the changes there into 5.02, while keeping it compatible with ANSI only calls. This solved the issue, so whatever changed there seems to be the answer. Thanks for testing this, it led me in the right direction.

Comment: @fourwhey can you share this source? I´m facing the same problem here, on Windows 10, it throws an StackOverflow exception on function: `QRPDFFilt.cvtInt`.

Comment: @CelsoMarigoJr I'm sorry but I can't since this is a commercial product. If you have a license you can get in touch with support@quickreport.co.uk, I sent it to them some time ago.

Comment: @fourwhey ok... No problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
uses ComObj, ActiveX, StdVcl; 



if Printer.Printers.Count>0 then
  begin
 FSWbemLocator := CreateOleObject('WbemScripting.SWbemLocator');
 FWMIService   := FSWbemLocator.ConnectServer('localhost', 'root\CIMV2', '', '');
 FWbemObject   := FWMIService.Get(Format('Win32_Printer.DeviceID="%s"',[Printer.Printers.Strings[0]]));
 if not VarIsClear(FWbemObject) then
 FWbemObject.SetDefaultPrinter();
 end;
```

new solution

Windows 10 have not default printer with this code u can set the default printer

Comment: interesting, I'm wondering whether set a default printer in windows 10 will make the error go away or not